# Перезагрузка формы

Tags: javascript, html, form, submit

```html
function ready()
{
    const elemForm = document.getElementById('submitForm');
    const elemInputLogin = document.getElementById('inputLogin');
    const elemInputPassword = document.getElementById('inputPassword');
    
  function fSubmit(event)
    {
        event.preventdefault();
    }
    
  elemForm.addEventListener('submit', fSubmit);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);

<form method="POST" action="" id="submitForm">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Логин:</td><td><input type="text" id="inputLogin" class="input text" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Пароль:</td><td><input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="input text" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="input button submit" value="click" /></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Есть простая форма. При нажатии на кнопку происходит перезагрузка формы, как отключить её?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: `event.preventdefault();` тут опечатка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно не так

```
preventdefault
```

а вот так

```
preventDefault
```